# How to debug Fable using Visual Studio (not Code)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, f#, visual-studio-debugging, fable-f#

I know it is possible to debug Fable apps in VS Code and hit breakpoints, but I haven't seen any examples of such when using Visual Studio. How can one debug Fable apps using Visual Studio, being able to hit breakpoints, inspect variables, etc.?